# One Paypal API request isn't sending all the data, but others are

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I'm making something that uses Paypal and having a bit of trouble with my final step in the Paypal process. I have four calls to the Paypal API which work just fine, but the last one doesn't. To start, here is my curl function

```
function curl($PayPalMode,$nvpreq) {
    $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.".$PayPalMode.".paypal.com/nvp";

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

    $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

    $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);
    $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
    foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
        $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
        if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
            $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
        }
    }
    if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
        return "Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.";
    }

    return $httpParsedResponseAr;
}
```

Then, as mentioned this is used four times for different things, for example

```
$data_set = array(
    USER = $PayPalApiUsername,
    PWD = $PayPalApiPassword,
    SIGNATURE = $PayPalApiSignature,
    METHOD = "SetExpressCheckout",
    VERSION = urlencode(109.0),
    L_BILLINGTYPE0 = "RecurringPayments",
    L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0 = urlencode($paypal_obj->name)." (".urlencode($paypal_obj->price)."/Month)",
    CANCELURL = $PayPalCancelURL,
    RETURNURL = $PayPalReturnURL,
    CURRENCYCODE = $PayPalCurrencyCode
);
$nvpreq_set = http_build_query($data_set);
$set_express_checkout_curl = curl($PayPalMode,$nvpreq_set);
```

These first four requests (which also includes GetExpressCheckoutDetails, CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile, and GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails) all work fine, using the exact same method. However, the fifth and final one does not. This is using UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile as I sometimes want to give uses a trial month. It uses the exact same method as above

```
$data_update = array(
    USER = $PayPalApiUsername,
    PWD = $PayPalApiPassword,
    SIGNATURE = $PayPalApiSignature,
    METHOD = "UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile",
    VERSION = urlencode(109.0),
    PROFILEID = $payer_id,
    TRIALBILLINGPERIOD = "Month",
    TRIALBILLINGFREQUENCY = 1,
    TRIALTOTALBILLINGCYCLES = 1,
    TRIALAMT = 10.00,
    CURRENCYCODE = "GBP"
);
$nvpreq_update = http_build_query($data_update);
$update_profile_curl = curl($PayPalMode,$nvpreq_update);
```

However, this does not work, and instead returns error 11510 - Invalid trial amount, Trial amount must be >= 0. Upon sending a support message to Paypal they confirmed that the TRIALAMT was not being passed, and this was all they were receiving

```
Timestamp 20-Jan-2016 17:40:41 GMT (1453311641)
UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest 
profileid "(profileid)"
currencycode "GBP"
trialtotalbillingcycles "1"
method "UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile"
version "109"
user (email address)
correlation_id (correlation id)
```

As you can see, it is not just the TRIALAMT that isn't being passed, it is also TRIALBILLINGPERIOD and TRIALBILLINGFREQUENCY. This is the only instance in all of this that some data isn't being passed - and my question is does anyone know why this might be? I am completely lost with this, I have no idea why these bits of data wouldn't be passed, unless there is something wrong with my final request?

Comment: Does it work if you enclose the digits in inverted commas as in: - "10.00" and "1" even "109.0" so they are passed as text values instead of numeric ones?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, urlencoding your params (inside curl function) may prevent lost of data, as is explained in this url: http://www.brandonchecketts.com/archives/array-versus-string-in-curlopt_postfields

> ...So, when sending POST requests in PHP/cURL, it is important to urlencode it as a string first.
>
> This will generate the multipart/form-data version
>
> ```
> $data = array('name' => 'value', 'name2' => 'value2');
> curl_setopt($curl_object, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $data)
> ```
>
> And this simple change will ensure that it uses the application/x-www-form-urlencoded version:
>
> ```
> $data = array('name' => 'value', 'name2' => 'value2');
> $encoded = '';
> foreach($data as $name => $value){
>     $encoded .= urlencode($name).'='.urlencode($value).'&';
> }
> // chop off the last ampersand
> $encoded = substr($encoded, 0, strlen($encoded)-1);
> curl_setopt($curl_object, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $encoded)
> ```